# implement getchar with buffered read

Tags: c

I was trying to implement `getchar()` function using `read` function in unistd.h.

I know `read(0,buffer,1)` is equivalent to `getchar()`, however, it takes too many system calls.

Is there a way to implement `getchar()` function using less system calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes -- read a larger buffer (e.g., at least a few kilobytes) full of data. When the user calls getchar, return a char from the buffer unless it's empty. If it is empty, refill the buffer first, then return a char.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jerry. However, What if user enters less than that buffer?

Comment: @user2188908: For an interactive stream where the user is entering things directly, you typically want to use line buffering -- i.e., read up to the new-line. Given the low speed of interactive input, you generally don't care much about speed in this case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of `getchar()`:

```
int mygetchar(void)
{
        static char buf[BUFSIZ];
        static char *bufp = buf;
        static int i = 0;

        if (i == 0)
        {
                i = read(0, buf, 1);
                bufp = buf;
        }
        if ( --i >= 0 )
        {
                return  *bufp++;
        }

        return EOF;
}
```